# Thymeleaf failed query param resolution

Tags: java, html, spring, url, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf version 2.1.4, When sending query param to an URL, I wanted to print the string. Instead of proper string, it prints string object like this `[Ljava.lang.String;@767a8ed5`. I try to print it in HTML like this:

```
<p th:text="${param.message}"></p>
```

The url is like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/about?message=This%20is%20about%20page.
```

Any help will be appreciated with mistakes in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Param object returns an array of strings for each parameter, even if there's only one value for that parameter, that's why you are seeing the object reference `[Ljava.lang.String;@767a8ed5`. You may access the first element of that array by using an index instead, like:

```html
<p th:text="${param.message[0]}"></p>
```